# Math library seems not to be found by gcc

Tags: c, math, gcc

I'm trying to execute a very simple code in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef M_PI
 #define M_PI 3.14
#endif 

double cosrad (double n)
{
    double rad = n*(M_PI)/180.0;
    double res = cos(rad);
    return res;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf ("cosrad 90 = %f\n", cosrad(90));
    printf ("cos pi/2 = %f\n", cos(M_PI/2.0));
    return 0;
}
```

but while compiling with this command line (with -lm), I get an error. The math library seems not to be found.

```
$gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -O0 -lm -g -o foo foo.c
.c:12: undefined reference to `cos'
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
```

That is really strange because the code :

```
 printf ("cos pi/2 = %f\n", cos(M_PI/2.0));
```

(without the cosrad function) works well !

Does someone may have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: @AlceuCosta `cosrad` is defined in the code above.

Answer (score 8):

You need to put the `-lm` option **after** the file that needs it (foo.c). i.e.:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -O0 -g -o foo foo.c -lm
```

The order of modules specified when linking is important: You need to put a module after the modules which referenced it.

The reason that `cos(M_PI/2.0)` did work is probably that the compiler replaced the value with a constant in that case, so linking to the `cos` function wasn't required.

Comment: gcc will optimise away constant trig functions?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, since version 4.3: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html

Comment: ah, my gcc 4.2 on MacOS X doesn't do it for -O0, but seems to for -O1

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem lies in `printf ("cosrad 90 = %f\n", cosrad(90));`
`cosrad` is defined to take `double/float` as arguments but here its find `int`
value.
Typecasting to `double/float` would help disappear this problem.

Good luck.

Comment: There is no need for a cast, `int` will be automatically converted to a `double` when calling `cosrad`.

Answer (score -2):

You must link explicit link the math library when you compile with gcc, but be carefull: math.h is full of errors and dangerous functions

Comment: Do you have any justification for the statement "math.h is full of errors and dangerous functions"?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: The pen is mightier than the sword, and the calculator is mightier yet.